# Nil check on form params not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've integrated a hidden field called nickname which should not be entered, if it is, it suggests a bot is filling it in and therefore should not process the action mailer.

Here's the code I have to do this filter:

```
if params[:nickname] == nil
  @contact = Contact.create(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    GenericMailer.contact_mailer(@contact).deliver
  else
    redirect_to root_path alert: "Oops! It looks like you have entered something incorrectly, please try again."
  end
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @contact, :url => {:controller => "footerlinks", :action => :contactcreate } do |lead|%>
    <%= lead.text_field :fullname, :placeholder => "Full name", onfocus: "this.placeholder = ''", onblur: "this.placeholder = 'Full name'" %>
    <%= lead.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", onfocus: "this.placeholder = ''", onblur: "this.placeholder = 'Email'" %>
    <%= lead.text_area :query, class: "height15", :placeholder => "Query", onfocus: "this.placeholder = ''", onblur: "this.placeholder = 'Query'" %>
    <%= lead.text_field :nickname %>
    <%= lead.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

However, upon re-trying the form it seems to completely bypass the if statement and deliver the email despite the nickname form field not being nil.

Comment: How does the form or at least the nickname input field look like?

Comment: Should be params[:contact][:nickaname] then, no? But @leo-correa is right, too.

Comment: Perfect, nice one mate!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the `params[:nickname]` is not nil but an empty string. Try doing `params[:nickname].blank?`

Comment: Tried but it's having the same effect, very weird!

Comment: Have you taken a look at what's inside the params hash? What do the logs display when you do a puts on them?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that `params[:nickname]` is not even there, it means it is nil,
you have `params[:contact][:nickname]`

Try doing

```
params[:contact][:nickname].blank? # instead of params[:nickname]
```